# python calculator program

Tags: python, python-2.7, calculator, cal

I wrote a simple calculator program by using functions, I don't know what exactly wrong with this code, its showing error. I did possible steps to debug this, but I couldn't.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def add():        
        print "Enter the two numbers to Add"
        A=int(raw_input("Enter A:"))
        B=int(raw_input("ENter B:"))
        c = A + B 

def sub():            
        print "Enter the two numbers to Subtract"
        A=int(raw_input("Enter A:"))
        B=int(raw_input("Enter B:"))
        c = A - B

def Mul():
        print "Enter the two numbers to Multiply"
        A=int(raw_input("Enter A:"))
        B=int(raw_input("Enter B:"))
        c = A * B

def Div():   
        print "Enter the two number to Divide"
        A=float(raw_input("Enter A:"))
        B=float(raw_input("Enter B:"))
        c = A / B

print "1: ADDITION"
print "2: SUBTRACTION"
print "3: MULTIPLICATION"
print "4: DIVITION"
print "0: QUIT"

while true:

    CHOICE = int(raw_input(("ENTER THE CORRESPONDING NUMBER FOR CALCULATION")) 

    if CHOICE == "1": 
        print 'ADDING TWO NUMBERS:'
        add(c):

    elif CHOICE == "2":
        print 'SUBTRACTING TWO NUMBERS:'
        sub(c):

    elif CHOICE == "3":
        print 'MULTIPLYING TWO NUMBERS:'
        Mul(c):

    elif CHOICE == "4":
        print "DIVIDEING TWO NUMBERS"
        Div(c):

    elif CHOICE == "0":
        return 0:

    else
        Print "The value Enter value from 1-4"
```

Error:

```
  File "cal_fun.py", line 44
    if CHOICE == "1": 
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 4):

**I've have tried to cover all of the problems with your code, of which there  are numerous.**

Starting with `syntax` errors:

```
# true needed a captial T
while True:   

    # Brackets were mismatched
    CHOICE = int(raw_input("ENTER THE CORRESPONDING NUMBER FOR CALCULATION")) 

    if CHOICE == "1": 
        print 'ADDING TWO NUMBERS:'
        # Calling a function shouldn't have trailing : 
        add(c)

    elif CHOICE == "2":
        print 'SUBTRACTING TWO NUMBERS'
        # Calling a function shouldn't have trailing :
        sub(c)

    elif CHOICE == "3":
        print 'MULTIPLYING TWO NUMBERS'
        # Calling a function shouldn't have trailing :
        Mul(c)

    elif CHOICE == "4":
        print "DIVIDEING TWO NUMBERS"
        # Calling a function shouldn't have trailing :
        Div(c)

    elif CHOICE == "0":
        # can only return from a function use exit here instead
        exit()

    # else needs a trailing :
    else:
        # No capital P for print
        print "The value Enter value from 1-4"
```

The code now has no `syntax` errors but still has many problems.

1. You pass `c` to your function, `c` is never initialized, what is `c`?
2. Your function doesn't take arguments `def add():` *(even though pass the mysterious `c` value)*.
3. Your function doesn't `print` or `return` the result it just computes.
4. You store `CHOICE` as an `int` are do comparisons with strings so the `else` case is always executed and there is no way to exit the loop *(infinite looping)*.

---

**Fixed code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def add():
        print "Enter the two numbers to Add"
        A=int(raw_input("Enter A: "))
        B=int(raw_input("Enter B: "))
        return A + B 

def sub():
        print "Enter the two numbers to Subtract"
        A=int(raw_input("Enter A: "))
        B=int(raw_input("Enter B: "))
        return A - B

def mul():
        print "Enter the two numbers to Multiply"
        A=int(raw_input("Enter A: "))
        B=int(raw_input("Enter B: "))
    return A * B

def div():
        print "Enter the two number to Divide"
        A=float(raw_input("Enter A: "))
        B=float(raw_input("Enter B: "))
        return A / B

print "1: ADDITION"
print "2: SUBTRACTION"
print "3: MULTIPLICATION"
print "4: DIVITION"
print "0: QUIT"

while True:

    CHOICE = int(raw_input("ENTER THE CORRESPONDING NUMBER FOR CALCULATION ")) 

    if CHOICE == 1: 
        print 'ADDING TWO NUMBERS:'
        print add()

    elif CHOICE == 2:
        print 'SUBTRACTING TWO NUMBERS'
        print sub()

    elif CHOICE == 3:
        print 'MULTIPLYING TWO NUMBERS'
        print mul()

    elif CHOICE == 4:
        print "DIVIDEING TWO NUMBERS"
        print div()

    elif CHOICE == 0:
        exit()
    else:
        print "The value Enter value from 1-4"
```

---

The code is now functional.

**Output:**

```
1: ADDITION
2: SUBTRACTION
3: MULTIPLICATION
4: DIVITION
0: QUIT
ENTER THE CORRESPONDING NUMBER FOR CALCULATION 1
ADDING TWO NUMBERS:
Enter the two numbers to Add
Enter A: 2
Enter B: 5
7
ENTER THE CORRESPONDING NUMBER FOR CALCULATION 2
SUBTRACTING TWO NUMBERS
Enter the two numbers to Subtract
Enter A: 2
Enter B: 5
-3
ENTER THE CORRESPONDING NUMBER FOR CALCULATION 3
MULTIPLYING TWO NUMBERS
Enter the two numbers to Multiply
Enter A: 2
Enter B: 5
10
ENTER THE CORRESPONDING NUMBER FOR CALCULATION 4
DIVIDEING TWO NUMBERS
Enter the two number to Divide
Enter A: 2
Enter B: 5
0.4
ENTER THE CORRESPONDING NUMBER FOR CALCULATION 0
```

Functional but not perfect, for instance no error handling for erroneous input.

Comment: I'm getting the same error in if statement even after doing all the modifications. The error is                                                    aslan@aslan-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/python$ python cal_fun.py 
  File "cal_fun.py", line 47
    if CHOICE == 1: 
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an end parenthesis on the previous line (a common cause of mysterious syntax errors), change:

```
CHOICE = int(raw_input(("ENTER THE CORRESPONDING NUMBER FOR CALCULATION"))
```

to

```
CHOICE = int(raw_input("ENTER THE CORRESPONDING NUMBER FOR CALCULATION"))
```

This is not the only syntax error in the program- you end many lines with `:` when you shouldn't, like:

```
    add(c):
    sub(c):
    Mul(c):
    Div(c):
```

You also

1. have no `:` for an `else` statement (it's required)
2. capitalize `Print` when it should be `print`
3. have a return statement outside of any function

There are also errors that are not syntax errors:

1. misspell `True` as `true`
2. compare `CHOICE`, an int, to a string like `"1"` or `"2"`
3. are passing a non-existent variable `c` to a function that takes no arguments

Comment: I'm getting the same error in if statement even after doing all the modifications."" The error in 47th line File "cal_fun.py", line 47
    if CHOICE == 1:"" 
                  ^

Comment: @PrabhuAre: Make sure you changed that `CHOICE = int(raw_input(("` line to `CHOICE = int(raw_input("` (the first change I suggested), that's the only explanation. You can edit your question to include your new code. (Also, are you sure you are editing the correct file, and that you saved?)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a variable `c` to your functions `add()` `sub()` etc. but they are defined to take no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

on top of the syntax errors already mentioned what I think you actually want is for each function to return values to the main programme loop, which will then display them:

```
def add():
    A=int(raw_input("Enter A:"))
    B=int(raw_input("ENter B:"))
    return A + B
...

while true:

    CHOICE = int(raw_input(("ENTER THE CORRESPONDING NUMBER FOR CALCULATION")) 

    if CHOICE == "1": 
        print 'ADDING TWO NUMBERS:'
        answer = add()
        print answer
    ...
```

or alternatively make the programme shorter by inputting A and B in the main loop then passing those as parameters to the calculating functions:

```
def add():
    return A + B
...

while true:

    CHOICE = int(raw_input(("ENTER THE CORRESPONDING NUMBER FOR CALCULATION")) 
    A=int(raw_input("Enter A:"))
    B=int(raw_input("ENter B:"))
    if CHOICE == "1": 
        print 'ADDING TWO NUMBERS:'
        answer = add(A, B)
        print answer
    ...
```

Comment: Would it be possible to access the add() function in other programs, if I go with this method.

Comment: In general you can't access functions in one programme from another unless they are stored as [modules](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html). You can however access the add function from any code in the same file. In the 1st version you simply call add() and in the second you have to tell it what to add - add(x, y).